# Is there any mistake in comparing strings in JS?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, string-comparison, tic-tac-toe

I'm making tic tac toe game and I'm facing issue. If user's input is not equals to **X or O** then it should print the message *Enter correct signs* but I have no idea what's wrong in my code. Only *else if's block* is not working properly.

here is code of that function :

```
let p1, p2, s1, s2;

function startGame() {
  playAgain();
  p1 = document.getElementById("p1").value;
  p2 = document.getElementById("p2").value;
  s1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
  s2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;

  if (p1 == "" || p2 == "" || s1 == "" || s2 == "") {
    alert("Enter the details.");
    playAgain();
  } else if (
    s1 != "X" ||
    s1 != "x" ||
    s1 != "O" ||
    s1 != "o" ||
    s2 != "X" ||
    s2 != "x" ||
    s2 != "O" ||
    s2 != "o"
  ) {
    alert("Enter correct signs.");
    playAgain();
  } else {
    alert("You can start the game." + p1 + s1 + p2 + s2);
    isStarted = true;
  }
}
```

Thank you :D

Comment: The code `if (s1 != "X" || s1 != "x")` will always be true, regardless of the value of `s1` because `s1` cannot be both `X` and `x` at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to "and" your conditions instead of "oring" them.

```
else if (
   (s1 != "X" &&
    s1 != "x" &&
    s1 != "O" &&
    s1 != "o") ||
   (s2 != "X" &&
    s2 != "x" &&
    s2 != "O" &&
    s2 != "o")
  )
```

I personally would make use of `every` function to make it even shorter and less repetitive:

```
const validInputs = ["X", "x", "O", "o"]

else if (validInputs.every((item) => s1 !== item)
      || validInputs.every((item) => s2 !== item)) {
...
```

Comment: That works but I think it's more difficult to comprehend than a solution using a simple inclusion test such as `validInputs.includes(s1)`.

Comment: It helped! Thanks for the suggestion of "every" function :D

Comment: You're very welcome. I love short functions ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems line a logic error on the if statement, i tried this and it works properly

```
if (
    s1 != "X" &&
    s1 != "x" &&
    s1 != "O" &&
    s1 != "o" ||
    s2 != "X" &&
    s2 != "x" &&
    s2 != "O" &&
    s2 != "o"
  ) {
```

But you also need to validate that s1 isn't equal to s2 because the users can type something like `s1='X', s2='x'` and it would be valid

Comment: Yes i'm aware of those same inputs but I was stuck at that point that's why I didn't put that case. Well thank you :D